# How to solve open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) issue?

Tags: android, file, google-api, google-drive-api, filepath

I am working on uploading a file to manage my app with google drive.
I am getting the issue below.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/android_asset/config.json: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

There is a file name config.json in my project asset folder.
I read many posts on the same issue on SO, but none of the solutions I found works for me.

Below is my code to upload my file.

```
 try {
            File fileMetadata = new File();
            fileMetadata.setName("config.json");
            fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList("appDataFolder"));

            java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File("file:///android_asset/config.json");
            FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("application/json", filePath);
            File file = mService.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
                    .setFields("id")
                    .execute();
            Log.d("File ID: ", file.getId()); // System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("File ID: ", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Does anyone have an idea why this issue is coming and how to solve it?

Comment: Did you check storage permissions?

Comment: @RaunakVerma yes I had give both permission in mainfest.xml

Comment: If your target SDK is **>22**, that's not enough.

Comment: In my android phone both read and write permission are give.

Comment: As I already said: *Not if the target SDK is **>22***.

Comment: Check that this file exists in this location and that its not named something like file:///android_asset/config.json      and that its not named something like config.json.json

Comment: `"file:///android_asset/config.json"`. That is not a file on the file system so you cannot use the File class. If your file is in assets than use the assets manager to open an input stream for the file and then read from the stream.